# webSql creates multiple database nodes in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

I am lil lost here, in the Chrome development tool the DB i created is replicated multiple time.

[image]

The first few nodes are actually empty, only the last node has the DB tables. As you can see from the image the last node expands.
What would cause this?
I use the following code, to ensure it does not recreate the db I even use an if statement.

```
if(!db)db=window.openDatabase(localStorage.DB_NAME,'',localStorage.DB_DESC,localStorage.DB_SIZE*1024*1024,function(){console.log('created a new DB')});
```

Comment: same here. did you figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same just happened to me. Figured it out: you have multiple verssions of your code running, so chrome lists a node for each version.
In my case, I had multiple nodes in the debugger window of my chrome extension's background page, which I had kept open while I tried different versions of my extension.
Closing the window and opening it again fixed this.

Comment: What if you don't have multiple versions of the code running? When you say multiple do you mean tabs open with the same page loaded? Our app still lists multiple databases even though there's only ever one tab open.

Comment: multiple versions means versions of the code, not multiple tabs open. open tabs are not relevant, the db is accessed from the single background page. If you change the code and reload the extension, but have other pages open or debugging sessions active, chrome will keep the old versions as well until you close their references.